# Vagrant cURL works but Mozilla doesn't

Tags: windows, curl, vagrant, localhost, mozilla

I have the following issue. I just configured Vagrant box on Windows 7. This is my first time to use Vagrant. Guest port 80, host 8008(8080 is in use). It's all working well but http://localhost:8008/ in Mozilla dosen't respond in any way. From the virtual mashine `curl 'http://localhost:80'` works as expected. From the local mashine `curl -v "http://localhost:8008/"`as expected too. I tryed different browsers and firewall off - notting. Restart win, restart browser, clear Mozilla cash - all the same. The server is Ubuntu.
This is the vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.50.4"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8008
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => File.join( "provision", "provision.sh")
end
```

I'm probably doing something wrong but I'm not sure what. Please for any suggestions what that may be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using both private IP and forward port - use one or the other

*Using forwarded port*

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8008
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => File.join( "provision", "provision.sh")
end
```

and from your host you will be able to access http://localhost:8008/

*using private IP*

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.50.4"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => File.join( "provision", "provision.sh")
end
```

and from your host you will be able to access http://192.168.50.4/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just fix it. Finaly forwarded port didn't start working but the private ID is OK.